# How to search the record in the sql adapter or datatable,

Tags: sql, winforms, c#-4.0, navigation

How to search the records in data-table,in my application I am having plenty of records.

For eg: After the searching completes I am getting 50 records out of 1000, from the table, now I want to do the first, next, previous and last record navigation for this searched records only. how can I do this, I have done for normal navigation(directly connecting to sql) but getting some difficulty in showing navigation in searched records.

Comment: Okay, just confirm you wants to implement paging functionality in datatable, right ???

Comment: @Krishnraj Ya i have to paging also,

Comment: @Sarvan Please check my answer and comment...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var results = from myRow in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
where myRow.Field<int>("RowNo") == 1
select myRow;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i assume that you have fetched data into **Datatable** using **"fetchData()"** method.

```
// Global variable    
DataTable dt_rec = new DataTable();
int rowCount = 1;
int lastRowNum = 0;
```

In the form_load event, you called the **"fetchData()"** method. After then you click on **"Next"** button click event which look like this.

```
private void NextButton_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (lastRowNum > rowCount) {
        rowCount = rowCount + 1;
        setControlValue(dt_rec.Rows(rowCount - 1));
    } else {
        Interaction.MsgBox("Record Not Found", "Test");
    }
}
```

And here is the **"Previous"** button click event.

```
private void Previous_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (rowCount > 1) {
        rowCount = rowCount - 1;
        setControlValue(dt_rec.Rows(rowCount - 1));
    } else {
        Interaction.MsgBox("Record Not Found", "Test");
    }
}
```

And here is the click event of **"First"** button.

```
private void FirstButton_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (rowCount != 1) {
        rowCount = 1;
        setControlValue(dt_rec.Rows(0));
    } else {
        Interaction.MsgBox("Record Not Found", "Test");
    }
}
```

And finally the **"Last"** click event.

```
private void LastButton_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (rowCount < lastRowNum) {
        rowCount = lastRowNum;
        setControlValue(dt_rec.Rows(lastRowNum - 1));
    } else {
        Interaction.MsgBox("Record Not Found", "Test");
    }
}
```

Here you find the **setControlValue()** method which will set the control value. For exa.

```
public void setControlValue(DataRow dr)
{

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["UserId"])) {
        txtUserName.Text = dr["UserId"].ToString();
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["WebUrl"])) {
        txtWebUrl.Text = dr["WebUrl"].ToString();
    }

    // and so on.....

}
```

Hope all these thing might help you...